# src-{i386,x64} folders in R package

Tags: r, rcpp, devtools

While installing an R package containing Rcpp code using the `devtools::install()` command, two new folders - `src-i386` and `src-x64` were created. This would not happen earlier. Also this happens on a Windows system only. I'm guessing this is a result of a new feature added in the `devtools` package.

Question: Should these folders be included in the git repository?

Comment: Use of devtools is not prescribed in Writing R Extensions, and as such is unofficial.  Use the official tools, and follow their behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for the tip!
The package that I am working on has a function in an R script and another in C++. For some reason, devtools is unable to handle that on a Windows system. The official tools work perfectly, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

Only `src/` should be included within a git repository.

The `src-i386` and `src-x64` folders are artifacts left over from a multi-architecture build on Windows (e.g. x86 and x64). These folders are the result of *R*'s the command line install using `R CMD INSTALL ...`, which is wrapped by `devtools`.